# Why Array *new Array; fails in C++?

Tags: c++, arrays, pointers, new-operator, typedef

I always thought `T *p = new T;` was valid C++ for all `T`... until I tried

```
int main()
{
    typedef int Array[2];
    Array *p = new Array;
}
```

and got this cute error I couldn't decipher:

```
error C2440: 'initializing' : cannot convert from 'int *' to 'Array (*)'
```

Could someone please explain why this is an error?

Comment: It's a pointer to a pointer because of your `typedef`.

Comment: `new Array` is the same as `new int[2]`, which returns an `int*`.

Comment: And here I thought I was done being surprised by C++.

Comment: @MarounMaroun: No I'm wrong (I deleted my comment) -- I misread the answer...

Comment: @jrok: Interesting... I didn't realize that. It's a duplicate all right. Thanks.

Comment: Go home, C++, you're drunk...

Comment: @Mehrdad I still don't get the answer there..

Comment: @MarounMaroun: jrok explained it in his comment above, does that make sense?

Comment: ``new int`` and ``new int[2]`` both return the same type. *MINDBLOWN*

Comment: @Mehrdad Neither would I, right until now. But it's only sane explanation :)

Comment: @quasiverse: Well, I would expect `new Array` to be equivalent to `new (int[2])` and return `int (*)[2]` whereas I would expect `new int[2]` to be equivalent to `new (int)[2]` which would return `int*`... but I guess it doesn't work that way.

Comment: @DietrichEpp: Yeah, pretty much.

Comment: (But at least I know what kind of code I'm gonna write for next year's obfuscated C++ contest...)

Comment: You can achieve what you want with `new int[1][3]`.

Comment: @jrok: Oh interesting... then I'll have to use `delete []` on the result instead of simple `delete`, right?

Comment: Yes, in both cases in fact.

Comment: @Mehrdad I agree. I... I can't even tell if this is intended or an oversight. Like... C++ has been used for so long that it seems like something this simple would be caught if it was unintended. On the other hand, I do agree that what you expected should be the resulting behaviour. How is this defined in the standard? Edit: I suppose this is answered in the link jrok added.

Comment: Another use case of auto? If you declare yor pointer as auto *p = new Array; you have any problem :)

Comment: @Manu343726 No, in that case you have a much bigger problem because you'll be deallocating it incorrectly - you should be using `delete[] p`, not `delete p`!

Comment: I'm not sure I really get the problem. This is just because dynamically allocating an array type is a special-case where a pointer to the first element is returned. You're allocating an array of `int`, so you get an `int*`.

Comment: @quasiverse: There's nothing "unintended" or surprising about it, really. Dynamic allocation results in a pointer, because you're going outside of the static type system. Just because you `typedef` something doesn't change that.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

If you dynamically allocate an array type, you get a pointer to its first element.

> *§5.3.4 [expr.new]* Entities created by a new-expression have dynamic storage duration. If the entity is a non-
>   array object, [...]. If it is an array, the new-expression returns a pointer to the initial element of the array.

So since you're allocating an array type object, you get an `int*` out of it:

```
int *p = new Array;
```

This is no different to not using the typedef:

```
int *p = new int[2];
```

This also doesn't match your `T *p = new T;` rule. That is, you definitely can't do this:

```
int (*p)[2] = new int[2];
```

---

I realise this confusion may have been caused by thinking of `new ...[]` as a special type of expression different to `new ...`, where `new Array` fits into the latter case. We often suggest it might be by saying things like "`new[]` should always match with `delete[]`". Well that rule is a little misleading. What is really meant here is that `new` with an array type should always be matched with `delete[]`.

Comment: I disagree. `new` with an array type should always be banned from your codebase.

Comment: @DeadMG That's the next rule.

Comment: And that's when `struct Array { int i[2]; }` saves the day. (You can also pass an `Array` objet to a function without making the array decay into a pointer).

Answer (score 2):

The problem here is that array type syntax in C and C++ is a jumbled mess, and `typedef`ing an array type to something that doesn't *look* so jumbled doesn't make it any less so.

The result, in an expression, of dynamically allocating an array is a *pointer*, not an array. The types are different.